# Transformar una cadena de texto en formato fecha

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Tengo el siguiente problema. Quiero transformar esta cadena de texto:

```
'01-01-2000'
```

En formato fecha. Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
df[columna] = pd.to_datetime(df[columna], format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

Pero me está arrojando el siguiente error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1000-01-01 00:00:00
```

Entonces la cuestión sería, ¿Cómo hacer para que me lo convierta pero sin considerar la hora, minuto y segundo?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La función to_datetime tiene un parámetro errors. `pd.to_datetime(df[columna], format="%d-%m-%Y", errors='ignore')` va a retornar tu input original sin tirar error.

En [documentación de pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) podés encontrar más info